# get a tooltip when hovering over a select list option using jquery

Tags: jquery

I need a jQuery plugin that can show the option's text as a tooltip when we hover over a selectlist which has multiple select enabled. Else, can we do it manually.. if so can you give me some samples.

[edit] I am using IE 8 and need this to work across all browsers [IE, Chrome, FF, Safari].

Comment: Sounds like a `giv me teh codez!1` question...

Comment: @red-X : as there is no plugin to support this kind of feature, this question sounds so.. may be you can help me with the logic alteast then..

Answer (score 1):

There is some good [tooltip](http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/simple-tooltip-w-jquery-css/). You can modify it to fit your needs.

This is how you can get current hovering option ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qShB3/)):

HTML

```
<select height="2">
    <option>hello</option>
    <option>by</option>
</select>
```

JS

```
$('select option').hover( function(){ 
        console.log( 'Hover on:' + $(this).html() ) 
    }, function(){
        console.log( 'Hover off from:' + $(this).html() )
});
```

Comment: But how do i get the current hovering option tag using jquery?

Comment: `$('select option').hover(
    function(){console.log('Hover on:' + $(this).html() ) },
    function(){ console.log('Hover off from:' + $(this).html() )
});`

Comment: This is not writing to the console in IE9, even if give `alert($(this).html());` this is not working.. any fixes?

Comment: try `document.write` or `$('body').html($(this).html())`

Comment: This is similar to what I want to do, but the jsfiddle isn't working for me on Chrome or IE11.